# Parent child tree with ID's spread through multiple arrays/tables

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, parent-child

I inherited a table structure that I have never seen for a parent/child tree. This is not your typical parent/child tree to array problem.

It involves 3 arrays; Companies, Divisions, Users

**Few Rules**

1. There is always a root node that is a company
2. A division can be a sub node of a company or division
3. A company can be a sub node of a company or division
4. Users never have any sub nodes

**Things I've tried**

I have searched like crazy to see if anyone else has had to do something similar and have found nothing. I went down the road of a recursive function and the reference method, starting with the company array. But once i need to start attaching the companies or divisions as children then checking if that division has any children companies or divisions, i get totally lost on how to make that go to any depth.

**End result im looking for**

This array structure. **[Look a this picture for the full structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbSKN.jpg)**

```
Array
(
    [company_799] => Array
            (
                [companyid] => 799
                [parent_companyid] => 0
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [companyname] => Main Company
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [user_3138] => Array
                            (
                                [userid] => 3138
                                [companyid] => 799
                                [company_divisionid] => 
                                [username] => test user 1
                            )
                        [division_58] => Array
                            (
                                 [divisionid] => 58
                                 [parent_companyid] => 799
                                 [parent_divisionid] => 0
                                 [division_name] => Division 1
                                 [children] => Array
                                     (
                                         [user_3139] => Array

       .. etc...
```

**Company Array**

```
    Array
    (
        [799] => Array
            (
                [companyid] => 799
                [parent_companyid] => 0
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [companyname] => Main Company
            )

        [800] => Array
            (
                [companyid] => 800
                [parent_companyid] => 799
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [companyname] => Sub Company 1
            )

        [801] => Array
            (
                [companyid] => 801
                [parent_companyid] => 800
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [companyname] => Sub Company 2
            )

        [802] => Array
            (
                [companyid] => 802
                [parent_companyid] => 0
                [parent_divisionid] => 59
                [companyname] => Sub Company of Division
            )
    )
```

**Divisions**

```
    Array
    (
        [58] => Array
            (
                [divisionid] => 58
                [parent_companyid] => 799
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [division_name] => Division 1
            )

        [60] => Array
            (
                [divisionid] => 60
                [parent_companyid] => 801
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [division_name] => Sub Division of Company
            )

        [59] => Array
            (
                [divisionid] => 59
                [parent_companyid] => 0
                [parent_divisionid] => 58
                [division_name] => Sub Division of division
            )
    )
```

**Users**

```
    Array
    (
        [3138] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 3138
                [companyid] => 799
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [username] => test user 1
            )

        [3139] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 3139
                [companyid] => 799
                [parent_divisionid] => 58
                [username] => test user 2
            )

        [3140] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 3140
                [companyid] => 799
                [parent_divisionid] => 59
                [username] => test user 3
            )

        [3141] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 3141
                [companyid] => 802
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [username] => test user 4
            )

        [3142] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 3142
                [companyid] => 800
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [username] => test user 5
            )
    )
```

Comment: I would start with users, add them to the (sub)division or company. Then add division info (that already has children attached if available) to the companies.

Comment: Thank you for your input RST. I have just started down this road. Problem is with how companies can be a child of companies and divisions. As well as divisions can be a child of divisions or companies. This is where i get locked up.

Comment: You have Company, Division, User. Take one user from the User  (remove from array) add it to the division/company it belongs to. Take next user and so on til the array is empty. Then do the same for Divisions, add them to a company or if just a division, add them to the Company array. You can check whether a record is a company or a division by checking the properties is has. Another way would be to use an additional array Main and add company and division to that array. I am assuming company index and division index don't overlap.

Comment: Oooo yes, i think that just clicked for me, gonna try that out tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks RST, i posted my answer below. If you see any way of optimizing it, let me know. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution i came up with. Not the most elegant, but it works. Thank you RST for the help.

build_tree() is basicly building as much the tree on the first pass of the function. At the end of the function, if there is still data in the company/divisions/users arrays, it will recursively call itself.

```
public function get_tree()
{
    $arr_treedata              = array();
    $arr_treedata['tree']      = array(); // Where the final tree will be stored
    $arr_treedata['companies'] = $this->get_companies(); // From mysql table
    $arr_treedata['divisions'] = $this->get_divisions(); // From mysql table
    $arr_treedata['users']     = $this->get_users(); // From mysql table

    return $this->build_tree($arr_treedata);
}

private function build_tree($arr_treedata)
{
    // Append company nodes
    if (count($arr_treedata['companies']) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($arr_treedata['companies'] as $str_companyid => $arr_company)
        {
            $str_search_key = FALSE;
            if ($arr_company['parent_companyid'] == 0 && $arr_company['parent_divisionid'] == 0)
            {
                // Root node found
                $arr_treedata['tree'][$str_companyid] = $arr_company;
                unset($arr_treedata['companies'][$str_companyid]);
            }
            else if ($arr_company['parent_companyid'] > 0 && $arr_company['parent_divisionid'] == 0)
            {
                // Company is a child of a company
                $str_search_key = 'company_'.$arr_company['parent_companyid'];
            }
            else if ($arr_company['parent_companyid'] == 0 && $arr_company['parent_divisionid'] > 0)
            {
                // Company is a child of a division
                $str_search_key = 'division_'.$arr_company['parent_divisionid'];
            }

            if ($str_search_key !== FALSE)
            {
                // Search for the key
                $arr_insertdata = array('children' => array($str_companyid => $arr_company));
                $arr_newtreedata = $this->search_tree_and_insert($arr_treedata['tree'], $str_search_key, $arr_insertdata);
                if ($arr_treedata['tree'] != $arr_newtreedata)
                {
                    // Key found and new tree data detected
                    $arr_treedata['tree'] = $arr_newtreedata;
                    unset($arr_treedata['companies'][$str_companyid]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Append division nodes
    if (count($arr_treedata['divisions']) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($arr_treedata['divisions'] as $str_divisionid => $arr_division)
        {
            $str_search_key = FALSE;
            if ($arr_division['parent_companyid'] != '' && $arr_division['parent_divisionid'] == '')
            {
                // Division is a child of a company
                $str_search_key = 'company_'.$arr_division['parent_companyid'];
            }
            else if ($arr_division['parent_companyid'] != '' && $arr_division['parent_divisionid'] != '')
            {
                // Division if a child of a division
                $str_search_key = 'division_'.$arr_division['parent_divisionid'];
            }

            if ($str_search_key !== FALSE)
            {
                // Search for the key
                $arr_insertdata = array('children' => array($str_divisionid => $arr_division));
                $arr_newtreedata = $this->search_tree_and_insert($arr_treedata['tree'], $str_search_key, $arr_insertdata);
                if ($arr_treedata['tree'] != $arr_newtreedata)
                {
                    // Key found and new tree data detected
                    $arr_treedata['tree'] = $arr_newtreedata;
                    unset($arr_treedata['divisions'][$str_divisionid]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Append user nodes
    if (count($arr_treedata['users']) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($arr_treedata['users'] as $str_userid => $arr_user)
        {
            $str_search_key = FALSE;
            if ($arr_user['parent_companyid'] != '' && $arr_user['parent_divisionid'] == '')
            {
                // User is a child of a company
                $str_search_key = 'company_'.$arr_user['parent_companyid'];
            }
            else if ($arr_user['parent_companyid'] != '' && $arr_user['parent_divisionid'] != '')
            {
                // User if a child of a division
                $str_search_key = 'division_'.$arr_user['parent_divisionid'];
            }

            if ($str_search_key !== FALSE)
            {
                // Search for the key
                $arr_insertdata = array('children' => array($str_userid => $arr_user));
                $arr_newtreedata = $this->search_tree_and_insert($arr_treedata['tree'], $str_search_key, $arr_insertdata);
                if ($arr_treedata['tree'] != $arr_newtreedata)
                {
                    // Key found and new tree data detected
                    $arr_treedata['tree'] = $arr_newtreedata;
                    unset($arr_treedata['users'][$str_userid]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($arr_treedata['divisions']) > 0 || count($arr_treedata['companies']) > 0 || count($arr_treedata['users']) > 0)
    {
        $arr_treedata = $this->build_tree($arr_treedata);
    }

    return $arr_treedata;
}

// Search the tree for an array key and merge the data
private function search_tree_and_insert($arr_treedata, $str_search_key, $arr_insertdata)
{
    foreach ($arr_treedata as $str_keyid => $arr_row)
    {
        if ($str_keyid == $str_search_key)
        {
            // Found key, merge in the provided data
            $arr_treedata[$str_keyid] = array_merge_recursive($arr_treedata[$str_keyid], $arr_insertdata);
        }
        else if (isset($arr_row['children']))
        {
            // Search Children
            $arr_treedata[$str_keyid]['children'] = $this->search_tree_and_insert($arr_row['children'], $str_search_key, $arr_insertdata);
        }
    }

    return $arr_treedata;
}
```

**Result**

```
        [company_799] => Array
            (
                [companyid] => 799
                [parent_companyid] => 0
                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                [companyname] => Main Company
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [company_800] => Array
                            (
                                [companyid] => 800
                                [parent_companyid] => 799
                                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                                [companyname] => Sub Company 1
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                        [company_801] => Array
                                            (
                                                [companyid] => 801
                                                [parent_companyid] => 800
                                                [parent_divisionid] => 0
                                                [companyname] => Sub Company 2
                                                [children] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [division_60] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [divisionid] => 60
                                                                [parent_companyid] => 801
                                                                [parent_divisionid] => 
                                                                [division_name] => Sub Division of Company
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [division_58] => Array
                            (
                                [divisionid] => 58
                                [parent_companyid] => 799
                                [parent_divisionid] => 
                                [division_name] => Division 1
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                        [division_59] => Array
                                            (
                                                [divisionid] => 59
                                                [parent_companyid] => 799
                                                [parent_divisionid] => 58
                                                [division_name] => Sub Division of division
                                                [children] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [user_3140] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [userid] => 3140
                                                                [parent_companyid] => 799
                                                                [parent_divisionid] => 59
                                                                [username] => test user 3
                                                            )

                                                        [company_802] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [companyid] => 802
                                                                [parent_companyid] => 0
                                                                [parent_divisionid] => 59
                                                                [companyname] => Sub Company of Division
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [user_3139] => Array
                                            (
                                                [userid] => 3139
                                                [parent_companyid] => 799
                                                [parent_divisionid] => 58
                                                [username] => test user 2
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Answer (score 1):

That is sort of what I meant. I would change two things but that is just me.

Start with customers because their parents are already present, either in division or companies. Then handle divisions, because their parents are also already present, in companies, and if not, than this division can be added as parent.

Handling it this way would remove a lot of the searching you are doing, you can just check array indexes to see if a parent is present.

I am not too fond of `if, elseif, elseif` structures. I would change it to

```
if ( ! empty($arr_company['parent_companyid'] ) {
   // add to company 
   // other actions 
   continue;
}

if ( ! empty($arr_company['parent_divisionid'] ) {
   // add to division 
   //other actions
  continue;
}  

// no company or division parent id    
// add to tree as new division/company
```